# How can I verify a Google authentication API refresh token?

Tags: php, api, oauth, google-oauth, google-authentication

Is there a way to check if the Google authentication refresh token is valid or not?

Currently, an invalid token is breaking my application (using PHP client library) and logging 401 Unauthenticated errors in the PHP log.

I've tried the following `tokeninfo` requests but they don't seem to support `refresh_token`, works well with `access_token`, though.

https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/tokeninfo?refresh_token=refreshToken

https://oauth2.googleapis.com/tokeninfo?refresh_token=refreshToken

Also looked into the docs: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/backend-auth

Error in PHP logs:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Google_Service_Exception: {
  "error": {
    "code": 401,
    "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "unauthorized"
      }
    ],
    "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
  }
}
```

PS! No error when a valid `refresh_token` is provided. Change one letter and it gives me the error.

Comment: 1) Where is this bad Refresh Token coming from? You should always stay in control of Refresh Tokens and never hand them out to clients not under your control. 2) A side method of validating a Refresh Token is to use it to generate a new Access Token.  A bad Refresh Token cannot generate a new Access Token.

Comment: 1) The amount of Refresh Tokens is limited - if the user is using other services that use Refresh Tokens they might hit the limit and the one stored in my database becomes invalid. 2) The problem with that is that an invalid token doesn't return `false` but gives a 401 error that breaks my app. Using this `if ( $client->refreshToken($refresh_token) )`

Comment: Why is your app breaking? You should handle the case and have the user reauthenticate.

Comment: When I run this `if ( $client->refreshToken($refresh_token) ){}` with a broken Refresh Token the PHP gives me error 500 and in the error logs I see PHP Fatal error posted in the question. With a valid Refresh Token, it works fine.

Comment: A 500 Error means your code is crashing. If this a library or your code?

Comment: I know. The problem is that it only crashes when the code runs with an invalid Refresh Token. Hence my question, how can I validate the Refresh Token. I'm using the PHP Client Library.

Comment: @SilverRingvee: Did you get any solution? I am stuck with the same issue for last few days